# Generating a set of sums

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be (not necessarily distinct) real numbers, and let $A$ be a multiset formed by taking the $2^n-1$ sums of nonempty subsets of the numbers. For example if $(x_1,x_2)=(1,1)$ then $A=\{1,1,2\}$, and if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,2,-3)$ then $A=\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$.

Obviously a multiset $A$ of $2^n-1$ numbers need not be generated by some $n$ numbers in this way. Or it can be generated in more than one way, for example $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-1,-2,3)$ generates the same set as above. If we know that $0\not\in A$, is it still possible that $A$ is generated by more than one multiset of $n$ numbers?

Comment: Also, do you mean that A is the set of the sums of all possible subsets of the $ x_1, ..., x_n $?

Comment: Yes, all possible nonempty subsets. I've tried finding examples of multisets of numbers that yield the same $A$. I'm interested in sufficient conditions for the multiset to be unique (if it exists) given any $A$.

Comment: There's no harm in including the empty sum. Given the multiset $a,b,\dots,r$, the generating function for the multiset of sums is $(1+x^a)(1+x^b)\cdots(1+x^r)$. So the question is whether we can have $(1+x^a)(1+x^b)\cdots(1+x^i)=(1+x^j)(1+x^k)\cdots(1+x^m)$ without having a nonempty subset of $\{\,a,b,\dots,i\,\}$ summing to zero. A possible plan of attack: reduce to the case where each element is rational, then to the case where each element is integral, then apply unique factorization of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is generated by $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ and also by $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n$. Then for each subset $I$ of $\{\,1,2,\dots,n\,\}$ there's a corresponding subset $J$ of $\{\,1,2,\dots,n\,\}$ such that $$\sum_{i\in I}x_i=\sum_{j\in J}y_j$$ This is a (homogeneous) system of linear equations with rational coefficients, so if it has a (non-trivial) solution, then it has a rational (non-trivial) solution.

Now if there's a rational solution, then, multiplying by a common denominator, there's an integral solution. Let's call it $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$. Then we have $$(1+x^{a_1})(1+x^{a_2})\cdots(1+x^{a_n})=(1+x^{b_1})(1+x^{b_2})\cdots(1+x^{b_n})\tag1$$ We may assume no $a_i$ equals any $b_i$, as otherwise we could cancel one term on each side and get a solution with a smaller value of $n$.

One or more of the $a_i$ might be negative. If so, then one or more of the $b_i$ must also be negative, and the sum, $-S$, of the negative $a_i$ must equal the sum of the negative $b_i$, since it will be the smallest element of $A$. Then we can multiply both sides of (1) by $x^S$ to get $$(1+x^{c_1})(1+x^{c_2})\cdots(1+x^{c_n})=(1+x^{d_1})(1+x^{d_2})\cdots(1+x^{d_n})$$ where every exponent is a positive integer.

Now let $c$ be the largest of the $c_i$, $d$, the largest of the $d_i$. If $c<d$, then the right side vanishes at $x=e^{\pi i/d}$, and the left side doesn't, contradiction. Similarly if $c>d$, so we must have $c=d$. Now we can cancel $1+x^c$ on the left and $1+x^d$ on the right, and repeat the argument. It follows that the $c_i$ are just a permutation of the $d_i$.

Now go back to (1). I claim that there must be a nonempty collection of the $a_i$ (hence, also of the $b_i$) summing to zero. But I'm having trouble seeing how to finish this off, so I'll leave it here until I can get back to it, or until someone else sees how to complete the argument.

Comment: Next we have $c_i:=|a_i|$ and $d_j:=|b_j|$, if I understood your argument correctly. So to sum up, you have then shown that: $|a_i|=|b_{\sigma(i)}|$ for some permutation $\sigma\in S_k$. Therefore, since all $a_i$ are distinct from $b_j$, we must have $a_i=-b_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: Finally, the subset of negative $b_j$'s that sum up to $-S$ must correspond to a subset of the positive $a_i$'s given by $a_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}=-b_j$ for each negative $b_j$, and the sum of those will be $+S$. Since the sum of the negative $a_i$'s is $-S$ and we have found a subset of the positive $a_i$'s that sum to $+S$, we are done.

Comment: Other than that, brilliant observations you gave in this answer - if my comments are of any value, feel free to use them to finish your nice answer!

Comment: Yep, @String, that should finish it. But now I'm thinking the whole reducing-to-rationals-to-integers bit was unnecessary. The whole argument could have been done assuming the numbers are reals. You can't use the $e^{\pi id}$ argument, but you don't actually need it.

Comment: Why can't you use the exponential argument ? By the way, how can you multiply both sides of (1)  and keep the shape $1 + x^{a_1}$ ?

Comment: @Des, I think you're right, the exponential argument is fine. For the multiplication, if $a<0$, then you multiply $1+x^a$ by $x^{-a}$ to get $1+x^{-a}$. And the negative $a_i$ add up to $-S$, so the total effect is to multiply by $x^S$.